# "File ended while scanning use of \FancyVerbGetLine"

Tags: errors, minted, xparse

The following LaTeX manuscript

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,minted}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{MyMinted}{}
  {\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||,mathescape=true]{c}}
  {\end{minted}}
\begin{document}
\begin{MyMinted} 
  double diff(double (*f)(double), double |$x_0$|) {
      return |$\frac{d(*f)}{dx}(x_0)$|;
  }
\end{MyMinted}
\end{document}
```

produces (upon compilation with `pdflatex -shell-escape`) the following error message:

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \FancyVerbGetLine.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

What's the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You know that it's a bad idea to wrap verbatim environments, don't you?

Comment: You can't  hide verbatim-like environments inside other environment.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I don't understand what this means, and how it relates to my code.

Comment: minted has to do a lot of catcode magic and needs to find the end command verbatim. Use e.g. the `\newminted` command to create a new environment, not \newenvironment or something similar. See section "Defining shortcuts" in the docu.

Comment: inside minted (like inside verbatim) `\ ` does not start a tex command it is just a literal character so `\end{MyMinted}` does not end the environment, minted is looking for the literal string `\end{minted}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Could you please spell out what I need to write, because I can't figure it out based on the documentation section "Defining shortcuts".

Comment: actually after rereading your question I think you want \VerbatimEnviromment, not \newminted.  I will add an answer.

Comment: What's the drawback with `\newminted`? I see none. Use `\newminted[MyMinted]{c}{escapeinside=||,mathescape=true}`

Comment: @EvanAad Works flawlessly for me

Comment: @egreg: Sorry, you're right. I've tried it again, and it does work. You should write it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How to add new minted environments is described in the section "Defining shortcuts" in the minted documentation. For you this means:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,minted}


\newenvironment{MyMinted}{\VerbatimEnvironment\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||,mathescape=true]{c}}{\end{minted}} 
\begin{document}

\begin{MyMinted}
  double diff(double (*f)(double), double |$x_0$|) {
      return |$\frac{d(*f)}{dx}(x_0)$|;
  }
\end{MyMinted}

\end{document}
```

[image]