# File ended while scanning use of \FancyVerbGetLine

Tags: errors

Error:

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \FancyVerbGetLine.
<inserted text>
```

Have already seen and tried workarounds mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400111/file-ended-while-scanning-use-of-fancyverbgetline) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400111/file-ended-while-scanning-use-of-fancyverbgetline?newreg=d4f19ffb4b8a47e9ab1f57e606c0e9d6).

Code: [Here](https://gist.github.com/sourabh2311/dc7b2c0c0c51575a3827d1a23e1b6fc5)

If I comment out lines 185 to 188, I get the above mentioned error.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Please, made a shorter example showing the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be no space between `\end` and `{minted}`.

The offending lines have

```
\begin {minted}{cpp}
string s = to_string (num);
\end {minted}
```

While the space after `\begin` is irrelevant, the one after `\end` is relevant and should be removed. With

```
\begin{minted}{cpp}
string s = to_string (num);
\end{minted}
```

you will be on track again.